# CASE when clause using

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @custid varchar(50) = null

select * 
from Items 
where ShowItemNlyCusLoggedInWeb = case when 
                                       @custid = not null then 
                                       ShowItemNlyCusLoggedInWeb=0 or isnull
```

This is not working for me.

Comment: `@custid = not null` - wrong. `@custid is not null` - correct.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Your query / case statement is incomplete. refer [case msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)

Comment: Maybe add some sample data and expected results to your question. Clearly, nobody currently understands *what you're trying to achieve* and just saying things like "not working" doesn't help us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @custid varchar(50)=null

select * 
from   Items 
where  (ISNULL(ShowItemNlyCusLoggedInWeb,0) = 0 OR @custid IS NULL)
```

Comment: if @cusid is null i want to filter something if not null i want show all data

Comment: Which column are u going to use to filter data. is it still `ShowItemNlyCusLoggedInWeb` ? @SatG_shanu

Comment: yes still it is...if @cusid is not null i will show ShowItemNlyCusLoggedInWeb 0 values if cusid isnull i will show 0 and 1 values

Comment: Please see edit. I am now on mobile and can't format my pist properly. It should work. I assume that column only has 2 possible values? 0 and 1 (and maybe a null)

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this

```
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN @custid IS NOT NULL AND ShowItemNlyCusLoggedInWeb = 0  THEN 1
               WHEN @custid IS NULL AND ShowItemNlyCusLoggedInWeb IN (0,1)  THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
```